# Xunit initialize issues

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am having some issues to properly initialize my db adaptor class in my unit test case where the constructor of my dbadaptor class also initialize a vault to connect
and fetch our connection string

Below is the adaptor class that connects to our db

```
public class DBAdapterService : IDBAdapterService
{
    private readonly AppSettings _settings;
    private IVaultService _vaultService;
    public DBAdapterService(IOptions<AppSettings> settings, IVaultService vaultService)
    {
        _settings = settings?.Value;        
        _vaultService = vaultService;
    }
    
    public void Retrieve(string command)
    {
      //call configure of vault to get credentials
        using (var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
        {           
            //open connection using above connection string
            //execute command
        }    
    }
}
```

Below class connects to our vault and dynamically gets our connection string

```
public class VaultService : IVaultService
{
    public VaultService()
    {
        //some initialization
    }
    
    public async Task<Credentials> Configure()
    {
      //code to connect to vault and get credentials
    
       return vaultCredentials;
    }
}
```

//Xunit Test using Moq

```
[Fact]
public async Task get_data()
{
    Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>> appsettingMock = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
            appsettingMock.Setup(i => i.Value).Returns(new AppSettings
            {
               //settings some appsettings here
            });
    Mock<IVaultService> mockVault = new Mock<IVaultService>();
    
    //Is below the correct way to set vault as this doesnt seems to work
    IDBAdapterService dbadapterService = new DBAdapterService(appsettingMock.Object, mockVault.Object);
 
    //futher code to get data from db
}
```

When I run my above unit test I get error as "object reference not set to instance error", thats because my connection string is not fetched and set proprly from vault

So if anyone can provide inputs to how can I properly initialize my vault and pass to my dbadaptor class.

I tried to put just the code relevant to the post so many other things might be missing.

Comment: It looks like this is an integration test that will execute using an actual database, so it needs a real database connection. In that case I recommend taking this part - `//call configure of vault to get credentials` - out of this class. This class shouldn't be responsible for retrieving a connection string. It should just receive one. Or make it more abstract - it doesn't "configure anything with a vault", it just gets a connection string. Then that's easy to mock with something that provides a connection string to your test database.

Comment: I basically agree with @Scott reply re separation of concerns and that your DB adapter should not explicitly rely on Vault for getting the con. string but rather a more abstracted connection string provider.
Anyway, if you still want to use the vault provider you simply need to Setup the call for .Configure(..) on your Vault mock to explicitly return the expected con. string.
You would still need an actual DB ref by this con. string for your adapter to run properly. consider using some containerized image of a DB pre-set with the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will eventually take out vault connection from my adaptor class, but that would require some changes as we have lot of dependency at this time. Is there any temporary workaround that I could use in my unit test cases for now till the time I make the actual changes,